# Difference Between Given Code for lastRow and lastColumn

Tags: excel-2013

I've inherited some code that attempts to select the last row and last column.

```
lastColumn = ActiveSheet.UsedRange.Column - 1 + ActiveSheet.UsedRange.Columns.Count

lastRow = ActiveSheet.UsedRange.Rows(ActiveSheet.UsedRange.Rows.Count).Rows
```

A couple questions:

1. What exactly is "UsedRange" doing?
2. Can someone give a brief explanation of each piece of code and why there is a difference between the two pieces of code for last row and last column. It seems like they should be the same.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

UsedRange is a range of cells previously defined in the code through some method, likely starting from the top left and extending via .End(x1Down) and .End(x1ToRight) but without the rest of the code it's hard to say exactly.

lastcolumn takes the column number of the first column, and adds the number of columns in the selection which gives the column number reference of the final column. (the - 1 is just for a correction in offsetting)

lastrow calls for the row number of the last row in the range, which is found from the count operand.  The last word in that line should also be Row, not Rows.

There should be no reason why each method would not work in place of the other, they each accomplish their task though somewhat different methods.